# How do you read all the ACLs on a particular host and change the name of a group when present?

Tags: linux, permissions, rhel, acl, setfacl

I am trying to read all of the ACLs on a particular host using the following command:

`getfacl -R /`

What I want to do is look for groupA in each ACL and if groupA is present, change it to groupB, otherwise leave it alone.

`getfacl -R / | setfacl -g:groupB dir`

The above is not working for me, but any direction anyone can point me in would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're second command isn't good.

In order to change ACL of dir allowing groupB **rwx** permissions:

```
setfacl -m g:groupB:rwx dir
```

Second, even if your command was good, you'd have a problem with

> if groupA is present, change it to groupB

There is a way to copy ACL from one file to another, as seen in `man setfacl` examples:

```
getfacl file1 | setfacl --set-file=- file2
```

One solution to your problem would be to go through all files, one by one, change groupA for groupB with sed and copy changed ACL to the same file. That way if there is groupA in ACL it will be changed to groupB, otherwise nothing will happen. Something like:

```
for file in $(find / -xdev) ; do getfacl $file | sed s/groupA/groupB/ | setfacl --set-file=- $file ; done
```

I don't know if there is a more efficient solution, or maybe a way to do same thing with find only...